# If/else loop for value option in input tag of JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I have a JSP code as follows. I want to insert an if/else loop inside the input form. If ${experimentList.type} == GRO-seq, then I want the values to be "positive" and "negative". Else, I want the value on the buttons to be shown as "bigWig File" and "bigWig File". I searched extensively for this type of looping but did not find a working solution. Thanks!

```
<c:forEach items="${experimentList}" var="experimentList">    
        <tr>
            <td>${experimentList.FGCID}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.person}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.type}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.factor}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.tissue}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.condition}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.sample}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.name}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.date}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.comments}</td>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getfiles" method="post">  
            <td><input type="submit" name="track_1" value="positive" /><input type="hidden" name="track1" value="${experimentList.track1}" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="track_2" value="negative" /><input type="hidden" name="track2" value="${experimentList.track2}" /></td>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 input fields with name track1 and 2 input fields with track2.

Comment: The 2nd one for each is a hidden field, just to get the path stored in ${experimentList.track1} and ${experimentList.track2}. The first one is for displaying the values "positive" and "negative". I need to change only the 1st field in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code to following

```
<td>
     <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${experimentList.type eq 'GRO-seq'}">
             <input type="submit" name="track_1" value="positive" />   
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
             <input type="submit" name="track_1" value="bigWig File" />
         </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
    <input type="hidden" name="track1" value="${experimentList.track1}" />
</td>
<td>
     <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${experimentList.type eq 'GRO-seq'}">
             <input type="submit" name="track_1" value="negative" />   
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
             <input type="submit" name="track_2" value="bigWig File" />
         </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
    <input type="hidden" name="track2" value="${experimentList.track2}" />
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you Nikhil! Works perfectly.

Comment: @Mana - Good to hear that :)